# Where do the X-Men get all their money/funding?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men

Charles Xavier's father was a "wealthy nuclear scientist". In the beginning, Charles personally bankrolled the Xavier Institute/X-Men using his family's money.

This included, but was not limited to things like upgrading the mansion to house the training levels, providing a helicopter (the predecessor to the Blackbird jet), providing and replacing uniforms, providing health care for injured students, and rebuilding/repairing the mansion and parts of the Danger Room  repeatedly.

These have all been recurring costs. The mansion has been damaged or outright destroyed a ridiculous number of times. X-Men can't get into a fight without someone's uniform getting damaged.

In one of the more recent stories (I believe it was an early issue of Wolverine & The X-Men), a comment is made about how the X-Men are pretty much bankrupt.

**Where has all this money come from over all these years?**

Xavier may have had a large war chest to start with, but no other income has ever been mentioned to my knowledge. Student's tuition could account for some of it, but there's no way that's going to fund everything.

Comment: [Credit Default Swap](http://money.howstuffworks.com/credit-default-swap.htm) trading? Xavier replacing Bin Ladon as a member of the [Carlyle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Carlyle_Group)?

Comment: I can't pin down if it was from one of the animated series, or the comics, but I seem to remember Xavier demonstrating he took the wealth his father left him and used it to invest in certain companies, which he then used his powers to manipulate into turning profits to continue funding the Institute.

Comment: Money laundering for Mexican drug cartels. Oh wait, no, that's HSBC not the X-Men.

Comment: I got one word for you: [Herbalife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbalife).

Comment: @Monty129: That seems rather hypocritical considering how he teaches his students not to abuse their powers.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté I'm pretty sure it doesn't say anywhere he's not allowed to be a hypocrite.  In fact it's been proven quite often that he *is* a hypocrite.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Other members of the team are also wealthy and/or highly placed:

- [Emma Frost](http://marvel.wikia.com/Emma_Frost_%28Earth-616%29#cite_note-Generation_X_.23-1-0) is very wealthy (both inheritance and her own business ventures). Covered in Generation X #1.
- [Angel (Warren Worthington)](http://marvel.wikia.com/Warren_Worthington_III_%28Earth-616%29) is also a billionaire (on Fortune 500 list). He definitely bankrolled other superhero teams (LA defenders) - and in Wolverine & X-Men #4, page 5, Logan says he will also fund Logan's Jean Grey School for a bit.

  - When he's broke after being declared incompetent in W&X-M #6, Logan takes a telepathic student onto some space Casino where they win tons of money. Shark. Jumped.
  - Except... they lose that money escaping from the Casino. Only to realize in the end that Krakoa (living rock) that the school was built on can *grow* diamonds. Free Money.
- Storm (Ororo Munroe) was the Queen of Wakanda. Whether that gave her spare change is unclear.

Comment: Emma is a fairly recent addition (last 10 years or so?). Storm was only married to Black Panther for a few years, as I understood, and are divorced now. Warren was my first thought, but I was unsure especially since he's currently a student at the Jean Grey Institute and they still have financial issues.

Comment: Wasn't Warren directly responsible for funding Mutants Sans Frontiers?

Comment: Also Emma, Angel, Jean, Sunspot, Psylock and a few others all have ties to the Hellfire Club, so that's also a possible source of income/funding.

Comment: Their running costs could also be relatively low since: they don't need to pay any of the instructors/members, and they have mutants who can possibly help repair the mansion/equipment using their powers (e.g. technomancy/technopathy, psychokinesis, super speed, super strength, elemental transmutation, phasing, replication, etc.); also, their level of technology would make medical care and uniform replacement pretty cheap. And they might also receive grants and donations from alums like other schools.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté - um... Sorry, your comment is 100% completely invalidated by the comics themselves. Both by Logan AND Charles X. Very explicitly.

Comment: @DVK: I haven't read much of the comics so that may well be true. But at least from the movies and animated shows, it seems like they have their own medical facilities and pretty high tech gear so probably don't have to pay anyone $1000~5000 for an MRI.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté - don't read "much". Just W&XM #1 and #7. Or ask :)

Answer (score 4):

They had many people that had large portions of money...

You are right that Professor X Bankrolled most of the operations for the X-Men until recently..

One of the few mutants that had a lot of money was Warren Worthington III aka Archangel from research online it seems that he helped fund the X-Men from his company Worthington Industries' profits.

Wolverine seems to have quite a bit of money because he funded the Jean Grey School out of pocket.

Emma Frost is a billionaire as previously stated...

Gambit wrote a million dollar check to Bullseye to buy him off from killing him...

So there's quite a few people who have lots of money.

Comment: OK answer, but in general references are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

First off yes, the Xavier family were very rich indeed. What has never been mentioned is if any prior Xavier's had mutant gifts or even Charles... if the money had been in the family for generations, it's likely a mutant was involved somewhere in gaining it.

Xavier is likely involved in holding a lot of patents for tech that is onsale in the X-World... if XMen have a gadget, between he and McCoy they likely have developed a "civilian" offshoot of it.

While I doubt Xavier would be unethical enough to use his powers directly for personal gain, where would inevitably be occasions where he would "pcik up" information from people. For example he knows the "cure" is being announced. If he can get other such information that can help his cause then I am sure he would use it under the "greater good" argument.

Answer (score -4):

Quicksilver (Peter Maximoff) is a kleptomaniac. He has a disorder where he steals stuf because he can't help it. His pace helps him in accomplishing this task. Xavier instructed Quicksilver to steal gold from the gold reserves. He did, and the money went straight to Xavier's bank account

Comment: Do you have a source for this?  Because it not only seems speculative, it seems out of character for Xavier to encourage such a theft.

Comment: Do you have any source or reference for any of this, aside from *Days of Future Past* depicting him as a thief?